# Is it possible to use setSchemaUpdateOptions(ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION) from BigQuery load config in Dataflow with the built-in BigQueryIO.Write?

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I would like to use the [experimental option](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobConfigurationLoad.html#setSchemaUpdateOptions(java.util.List)) that allows me to update a BigQuery schema when performing a load job.

I'm using Dataflow and the built-in BigQueryIO.write from the SDK.

I saw that with a JobConfigurationLoad.setSchemaUpdateOptions(ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION) from the BigQuery API it's possible, but I can't find the equivalent with the BigQueryIO.

Does it exist somewhere or can I override some part in the BigQueryIO to do that ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, that experimental option is not yet exposed via the Dataflow/Beam APIs in `BigQueryIO`, and it would not be a trivial task to override something in in that class - I wouldn't recommended going down that route.

One workaround I can think of would be to redirect your sink to GCS instead of BigQuery, and then perform a normal BigQuery load job(s) at the end of your pipeline. That way you can use the option.

Comment: Seems like an option I'll try it out thank you very much ! How can I execute a simple load job after a pipeline executing asynchronously ? Can it be in the same code ?

Thanks

Comment: Simply run your pipeline, wait until it finishes, and then scoop up the files from GCS into BigQuery after using the API.

Comment: Thanks for the reco, I'll validate the comment once I've tried it successfully!

Comment: Hi, it does not seem to work. Write to GCS in json newline delimited works. However, the following doesn't work, tried with command line
`bq load  --autodetect  --max_bad_records=2000 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION  table.mytable  "gs://..."`

Error:
`BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'job': JSON table
encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 3484; errors: 2001.
Failure details:
- gs://...: JSON parsing error in
row starting at position 1825158333: . No such field:
th_xxx.`

Rows can have different keys.

Comment: So it is a very nice workaround but does not work in my case. However the sink to GCS then patch BQ schema then BQ Load job works fine, thanks !

Comment: Graham Polley, Any news?

Answer (score 0):

The support for [SchemaUpdateOption.ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.22.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.Write.SchemaUpdateOption.html) has been implemented with the release of Apache BEAM 2.18.0 in January. See [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/9524) the implementation details.